# Can I add scripts/tracking pixels programmatically through my app on the Shopify checkout page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

One way of adding scrips/pixels is from the admin panel. We can add our pixel on checkout page from there. I am developing some app and I need to add some pixel on the checkout page, can this be done through my app itself?

[image]

Can we add the pixel through code/some api call, the way we add any script or liquid file?

Comment: I would request an answer from the people who downvote randomly!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a script to the checkout using the ScriptTag API. Might work for you for your purposes... at least a few hundred others have embedded tracking info doing that.

Comment: just a small doubt. The tracking I want to add has to do with the variant ids and the customer id, which can not be fetched inside of the script as they are liquid tags. How to go about it? --- "{% for line_item in order.line_items %}<div><img=abc.com/record/{{customer.id}}/{{ line_item.variant.id }} width=1 height=1></div>{% endfor %}" -- This does not work inside the script, but works when added from the admin panel

Comment: True that. You are screwed if you want to access Liquid variables since ScriptTags only inject Javascript, and not only that, is only triggers with onLoad... Best you just get your merchant customers to paste your code.